# Как организовать группы пользователей

Tags: база-данных, php

Добрый день! Мы делаем небольшое приложение для нашей организации, где ключевыми группами пользователей будут выступать администратор, менеджера и клиенты. В нашем приложении можно будет обрабатывать заявки клиентов и работать с их заказами. Сейчас возник вопрос как организовать эти группы. Администраторов может быть несколько и у них могут быть определены одни права доступа, группе менеджеров можно добавлять подгруппы и у каждой подгруппы должны быть свои права.
Мы не можем определиться, как нам лучше организовать всю эту структуру. Есть несколько идей сделать так:

a) Группы админ, менеджер, клиент
Для менеджеров можно задавать группы и задавать права.
Также можно создавать остальные группы кроме админа, менеджера и клиента

б) Сделать одни общие добавляемые группы для менеджеров, а для админа и клиентов сделать фиксированные права доступа без изменения через базу данных, лишь через код.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вообще не делал это с нуля, а взял бы битрикс24 и попользовался.
Ребят, ну зачем городить велосипед, если есть готовое, и для вас оно будет идеальным.
Т.к. денег на разработку у вас не много, а чтобы написать хорошую систему нужен хороший, да и не один программист. и обойдется по минимуму в полмиллиона вам это - а оно вам нужно?

Answer (score 0):

[Сделай сам ACL. История разработки и написания несложной системы контроля доступов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109713/)

А вообще, гуглите по запросу `ACL` (access controll list)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте yii (это фреймворк).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTM-rOV7QLk

Comment: @anunak, ну хотя б вторую версию посоветовали, что ли.